# How to subscribe/unsubscribe each server in an auto-scaling group to SNS

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-sns

We are using Elastic Beanstalk to serve a REST API. Now, I want to develop an endpoint that serves notifications from an SNS-topic in an asynchronous way.

In order to receive those notifications, I need to subscribe the API-servers to the SNS-topic. How could I do this, with the scenario in mind that the EBS application can scale up to multiple servers and scale down again? I don't want a lot of dead links subscribed to the SNS-topic...

Answer (score 0):

In spring world we have a @PostConstruct which gets called on server startup, where you can subscribe "this.server" url to a given topic (you may need to build a proper working subscription url --using InetAddress et el).

Hence there is the working subscribe url using @RestController which confirms such an subscription instantaneously causes sns endpoint to be registered. Any new servers will do the same aka getting registered themselves (when new stack is created). We also need additional code for the consumption of notification messages subsequently and do something when confirmed subscription endpoints receive one.

Answer (score 0):

The way AWS wants you to use SNS is not by directly subscribing to it. Any notification which need to trigger something in a component should buffer notifications with an SQS queue. For this reason we chose to do Pub-Sub with a variable/scalable group of Subs using the Amazon managed Redis distribution.